# a planet in openGL: vector data or texture mapping?

Tags: vector, opengl-es, geometry, gis

I am completely new to 3D and started with Jeff Lamarche's [tutorials](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-table-of.html) as an introduction to openGL ES for iPhone, then so far, I am able to draw a spinning sphere, which will the base of my application.

What I want to do is render a planet Earth, thanks to 2D GIS vector data (polygones, lines or points with latitude/longitude or x/y coord).
I want to be able to turn different layers on/off and maybe able to identify an object that wold be touched.

My questions are :

would it be easier to rasterize my vector data to use them as image texture or apply the vector data onto the sphere (keeping in mind that I want to turn on/off the layers, the touch-enabled objects being optional)?

would it be easier to use a software like blender to draw the planet and add the layers rather than starting with the sphere I already have (procedural sphere)?

do the export tool from blender to opengl work well?

Comment: Blender's "Export to OpenGL" script is a quick hack and should not be used in any kind of real application. OpenGL is not a file format and OpenGL also doesn't specify any kind of model file format. You export into some file format and write a loader to retrieve the data from that and pass it to OpenGL rendering functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of question is difficult to answer in general. Technically your intention sounds a lot like if you would like to write a program like *Google Earth* or *KDE Marble*. Since you're referring to GIS data you will require very high resolution. Textures only make sense for limited resolution data.

GIS applications usually work using hybrid approaches where some vector data are rendered directly (roads, waters, borders), while others are rendered to texture and the texture, or more accurately texture tiles, being used as caches, for example for building outlines in dense cities or the like. However data as it comes from say OSM can be directly rendered as vector data, since they are not very dense.

Comment: Actually I only have a few data, the scale will be a global scale, the user won't zoom a lot. To summarize, it is a global map that I would like to render in 3D. Some 20 points, about 10 lines, and a few polygons.

Finally, what I am looking for is a way to calculate the coordinates of my vector data so that they appear on the surface of the sphere, i.e. without either being above or below the triangles of that sphere...
Aren't there any functions to project a 2D objects onto 3D objects?

Otherwise, considering the raster option, my images would need an alpha channel, is that posible?

Comment: With just 20 points, 10 lines you're far better of drawing those directly as vectors, than using a texture. However you probably want your lines to follow the sphere's surface curvature. For this you need to subdivide your lines and apply spherical interpolation, a task not being difficult. Your question about projecting 2D objects onto 3D objects is probably specific to turn spherical coordinates into 3D space, your 2D coordinates are azimuth (phi) and declination (theta), with a constant radius. Just look up how to transform spherical coordinates into cartesians.

Comment: thanks Datenwolf,

Is it possible to apply spherical interpolation with polygons too?

Comment: @Guillaume: Polygons as they are, are flat. However it is trivial to subdivide (tesselate) polygons into a finer mesh. If those polygons are already in spherical coordinates, then the subdivision is already spherical interpolated.

Comment: I could easily convert and import lines and points into Blender... but not polygons. After importing the contour as a line (there are no points inside the polygons), I can fill it but this does not follow the shape of a sphere at all.
Is that only possible in Blender? atool that would snap and apply my object onto the sphere?

Comment: @Guillaume: Triangles are flat, spheres are curved. You need to subdivide your triangles and project them to spherical coordinates. If you want to do this using Blender use the "Subdivision" and "Cast" modifiers.

Comment: Alleluiah, "cast modifier" is the tool I was looking for. Thanks.